# How to fill DTO with random data in order to test its serialization?

Tags: java, unit-testing, serialization, dto

I have a project which shares a DTO containing library with other services.

I want to add tests to this library which would check if each class is compatible with some serializer/deserializer.

Something like:

```
@Test
void canBeStoredAsJson() {
   final Dto x = this.fillWithRandomData(Dto.class);
   assertEquals(this.deserialize(this.serialize(x)), x)
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: You should test the serializer you are using in your project.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @Deadron There are several, Jackson among them. I clarified the topic a bit. I believe I need a way to create an instance of Dto with random data

Comment: I would say this is a bit outside of the typical responsibilities of a library. Testing things you aren't using seems a bit silly.  The configuration of the particular serializer could change how things operate in ways you cant predict.  If you write these tests its really only testing the capability of a particular serializer instead of anything relevant to you.  If you did find an issue what could you even do about it?

Comment: What you are doing is testing the serialiser and deserialiser and not your DTO. External libraries are mostly tested. So no need to test serialise and deserialise of the same.

Comment: @Suman I might have a missing constructor or annotation. I want to test for that. Also some serializers require a proper set of setters and getters, it can be cover by a test as well

Comment: I can recommend another way to test those rather than using serialiser and deserialiser. Refer [`meanbean`](https://github.com/meanbeanlib/meanbean/)library to test POJOs.